# Specification scala test all time result as passed

Tags: scala, testing, specifications, println

I'm new in scala, and I have some problems with tests

```
class TestSpec extends Specification {
sequential
   "Test" should new WithApplication(App.application) {
        "return true" in {
            val truFalse = true
            truFalse mustEqual false
        }
    }
}
```

Why all the time test response as

```
[info] Finished in 2 seconds, 217 ms
[info] 1 example, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
```

but result of the test must be FALSE

additionally, why I couldn't run test in debug mode and println?
The test dont stop on the breakpoints.

I'm running test by `sbt "testOnly *TestSpec"` and via IntelliJ IDEA button (for debug mode).

```
[info] TestSpec
[info] Test should
08:37:52,747 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
08:37:52,748 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/home/IdeaProjects/target/scala-2.13/test-classes/logback.xml]
08:37:52,748 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
08:37:52,748 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [file:/home/IdeaProjects/target/scala-2.13/classes/logback.xml]
08:37:52,748 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [file:/home/IdeaProjects/target/scala-2.13/test-classes/logback.xml]
08:37:52,839 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
08:37:52,839 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.ConversionRuleAction - registering conversion word coloredLevel with class [play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel]
08:37:52,839 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
08:37:52,842 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
08:37:52,844 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
08:37:52,860 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader] to OFF
08:37:52,860 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader] to OFF
08:37:52,860 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread] to OFF
08:37:52,860 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript] to OFF
08:37:52,861 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.logger] to INFO
08:37:52,861 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
08:37:52,861 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
08:37:52,861 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
08:37:52,861 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@1804e0b6 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
[info]   + new WithApplication(App.application) {
[info] Total for specification TestSpec
[info] Finished in 2 seconds, 125 ms
[info] 1 example, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
[success] Total time: 9 s, completed Jun 10, 2022, 8:37:55 AM
```

library:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test._
```

App.application

```
val env = Environment.simple(new File("."), mode = Mode.Test)
val context = ApplicationLoader.Context.create(
     environment = env,
)
```

Comment: Which library do you use for the test, syntax looks odd

Comment: Can you post more of the output please? Presumably you aren't seeing "test should: + return true" just above this... I'm guessing that maybe there's a default test that is passing, and you aren't running your own test properly... At least that's my hunch. Can you confirm in the output if a test is listed and if it's name matches your test's name?

Comment: added console output.
and it shows green test result with green mark

Comment: Check the code around/import, if I test the same with specs2, expected result is raised

Comment: It's duo to WithApplication(App.application). Something wrong with context.